# Why am I getting a "null" when I call this method? This is regarding file validation

Tags: java, subclass

When I run this method I receive "null", why?
Below is the code. I do not have a superclass because my assignment required only subclasses one of which is required to validate the file/create it if need be. This also happens to be the one I am having the most difficulty on.

```
System.out.print("Welcome to My Statistics Calculator"
        + "\nEnter the name of your text file (e.g. MyNumbers)"
        + "\nThe file extension will be added after entry."
        + "->: ");
String fn = input.nextLine();
String fileN = fn + ".txt";
String directFile = "C:\\W12Assignment\\" + fileN;

//calling subclass toValidate
toValidate vali = new toValidate(fileN, directFile);
System.out.println(vali.getValidDirect());
System.out.println(vali.getValidFile());
```

This is my subclass below:

```
public class toValidate extends W12Assignment {
    //constructors
    private String fileN;
    private File FN;
    private String directFile;
    private File directory;

    public toValidate(String fiNa, String dire) {
        fileN = fiNa;
        directFile = dire;

        //calling methods
        setValidFile(fileN);
        setValidDirect(directFile);

    }

    public File getValidFile() {
        return FN;
    }

    public File getValidDirect() {
        return directory;
    }

    private File setValidFile(String fileN) throws IOException {
        File FN = new File(fileN);
        if (!FN.exists()) {
            System.out.println("The file does not exist.\nCreating file...");
            FN.createNewFile();
            System.out.printf("The file now exists and is located here:\n%s\n",
                    FN.getAbsolutePath());
        } else {
            System.out.printf("The file already exists and is located here:\n%s\n",
                    FN.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        return FN;
    }

    private File setValidDirect(String directFile) {
        File directory = new File(directFile);
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdirs();
            System.out.println("The directory does not exist.\nCreating directory...");
        } else {
            System.out.printf("The directory does exist at this location: \n%s\n",
                    directory.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        return directory;
    }
}
```

Comment: 'When I run this method I receive "null"' - which method? what's the input? In case of an exception, please provide full stacktrace and show us which line triggers the NPE.

Comment: What you've shown is a code fragment, not a "method". Also, what do you mean by "receive" a null?  Do you mean you get a `NullPointerException`? Or does something print the word `null` when you didn't expect it.  You have to be much more explicit about exactly what is not working if you want to receive help. Please visit the [help] and read [ask] for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems You are hiding your class variable with your method variable. Try to change

```
File FN = new File(fileN);
```

to

```
 FN = new File(fileN);
```

on your method *setValidFile()*

Comment: Thank you so much, Lucas! I think I got too caught up in it to see where I went wrong.

Comment: It is not a class variable, you’re referring to an instance variable.